# wp_insert_post function inserts the same post 2 times

Tags: wordpress

Here is my code:

```
function insert_post() {
    global $wpdb;
    if (!isset($_POST['data'])) {
        exit;
    }
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes_deep($_POST['data']), true);
    $title = $data['post_title'];
    $content =  $data['post_content'];
    $img = $data['post_thumbnail'];
    $attach_id = $data['post_thumbnail'];
    $review_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_category' => array( 34 ),
        'filter' => true
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $review_post );
    $review = get_post( $post_id );
    $avatar = wp_get_attachment_image( $img, 'full' );  
    $common_list = array();
    $common_list['post'] = $review;
    $common_list['post_thumbnail'] = $avatar;
    $common_list['code'] = $code;
        $common_list['fb'] = $fb;
    $common_list['gender'] = $gender;
    echo json_encode( $common_list);

    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_insert_post', 'insert_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_post', 'insert_post');
```

Problem is that wp_insert_post() function inserts the same post 2 times. Can't find solution. What can cause this?

Comment: No, I've tried to do that just with one line but no success, when I remove first my code don't work at all, when I remove second the same result posts are repeating.

Comment: @rnevius you need the two for WordPress AJAX calls, one for logged in users and one for visitors. Possibly your JS is wrong, could you post that too?

Comment: here is js link: (http://havana.am/wp-content/themes/doc/js/test.js)

Comment: you need preventDefault() in your js (google it) . Otherwise the page will submit the form as well as perform the ajax function

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, here it is:

```
 if (!get_page_by_title($title, 'OBJECT', 'post') ){
        $review_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content'  => $content,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_category' => array( 34 ),
            'filter' => true
        )
}
;
```

Just checked whether a post with same title exists or not, if yes it doesn't call wp_insert_post.

Comment: What if you wanted to create a post with the same title?